# printf alternative when using "define _GNU_SOURCE"

Tags: serial-port, printf, flags, corrupt, termios

After reading https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-bypass-the-OS-buffering-during-I-O-in-Linux I want to try to access data on the serial port with the O_DIRECT option, but the only way I can seem to do that is by adding the GNU_SOURCE define but when I tried to execute the program, nothing at all is printed on the screen.

If I remove "#define _GNU_SOURCE" and compile, then the system gives me an error on O_DIRECT.

If I remove the define and the O_DIRECT flag, then incorrect (possibly outdated) data is always read, but the data is printed on the screen.

I still want to use the O_DIRECT flag and be able to see the data, so I feel I need an alternative command to printf and friends, but I don't know how to continue.

I attached the code below:

```
  #define _GNU_SOURCE

  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <termios.h>

  #define TIMEOUT 5


  int main(){
    char inb[3];  //our byte buffer
    int nread=0;  //number bytes read from port
    int n;        //counter
    int iosz=128; //Lets get 128 bytes
    int fd=open("/dev/ttyS0", O_NOCTTY | O_RDONLY | O_SYNC | O_DIRECT); //Open port
    tcflush(fd,TCIOFLUSH);
    for(n=0;n<iosz;n++){
      int s=time(NULL); //Start timer for 5 seconds
      while (time(NULL)-s < TIMEOUT && nread < 1){
        inb[0]='A'; //Fill buffer with bad data
        inb[1]='B';
        inb[2]='C';
        nread=read(fd,(char*)inb,1); //Read ONE byte
        tcflush(fd,TCIOFLUSH);
        if (nread < 0 || time(NULL)-s >= TIMEOUT){
            close(fd); //Exit if read error or timeout
            return -1;
        }
      }
      printf("%x:%d ",inb[0] & 0xFF,nread); //Print byte as we receive it
    }
    close(fd); //program ends so close and exit
    printf("\n"); //Print byte as we receive it
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: A serial terminal is not a block device, so trying to use the O_DIRECT option is illogical.  The article you cite clearly indicates that *"all operations must be done in "blocks" of the underlying sector size"*.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm no expert on this topic, just curious about it, so take this answer with a pinch of salt.

I don't know if what you're trying to do here (if I'm not looking at it the wrong way it seems to be to bypass the kernel and read directly from the port to userspace) was ever a possibility (you can find some examples, like [this one](https://lambermont.dyndns.org/snippets/radread.c) but I could not find anything properly documented) but with recent kernels you should be getting an error running your code, but you're not catching it.

If you add these lines after declaring your port:

```
...
int fd=open("/dev/ttyS0", O_NOCTTY | O_RDONLY | O_SYNC | O_DIRECT );    
if (fd == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d opening SERIALPORT : %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
    }
tcflush(fd,TCIOFLUSH);
....
```

When you try to run you'll get: `Error 22 opening SERIALPORT : Invalid argument`

In my humble and limited understanding, you should be able to get the same effect changing the settings on termios to `raw`, something like this should do:

```
struct termios t;
tcgetattr(fd, &t);            /* get current port state */
cfmakeraw(&t);                /* set port state to raw  */
tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &t); /* set updated port state */
```

There are many good sources for termios, but the only place I could find taht also refers to `O_DIRECT` (for files) is [this one](https://lwn.net/Articles/703785/).